# Editing normal PostGIS layer in ArcMap without installing Enterprise Geodatabase

Tags: arcgis-desktop, postgis, arcmap, arcgis-pro, enterprise-geodatabase

I have an open-source open-protocol product that uses PostGIS layers in PostgreSQL. I have a client now that wants to use ArcMap with this geographical data. I can connect ArcMap to the database as a PostgreSQL database, and then I can view the layer in ArcMap.  But, I can't seem to edit any of the attributes of the table.

Do I need to enable the enterprise geodatabase on the database just so that ArcMap can edit the attributes of a layer as a table?

That seems to create a bunch of crud in the database that I don't want. I really just want to edit the table that already exists in the database, the same way I can edit it in QGIS. I don't want to change the content of the database, nor add any new tables or anything, aside from just changing the attributes of one or two layers.

Or is there just some hidden setting somewhere, to make a PostGIS layer editable in ArcMap?

How is this supposed to work?

The company seems to have an enterprise license for ArcMap, so I don't think it's a licensing issue (but it could be.)

I'm sure there's someone at Esri could answer this question, but I'm hoping someone here is already using ArcMap with PostGIS tables.

PostgreSQL version is 12.  ArcGIS version seems to be ArcGIS Pro 2.9.2. Under Licensing, it seems to be a "Standard" ArcGIS Pro Named User License (not an Advanced). I notice there is no Data Interoperability installed in Esri Extensions, in the past I've needed that for basic WFS work, but I didn't think it was needed for PostGIS.

Comment: You **cannot** currently use ArcGIS editing tools on an feature class that has not been registered with a geodatabase. You can copy entire tables,  issue SQL commands with `arcpy.ArcSDESQLExecute`, and use `arcpy.da.InsertCursor`, but not the graphical editing tools.

Comment: Thank you @Vince for this answer!  I found some old support articles about how to register an existing database and as a geodatabase, and then add "normal" postgis tables to ArcGIS, I'll try to do it and report back.